# How to change the menu bar item by oncreate() method

Tags: android, menubar

In here I am having list of colleges. I favourite the particular college by using `menu bar` `Favourite_icon`.Then the `Favourite_icon` changed as `Favourite_icon1` When the college is viewed by some other time that menu bar `Favourite_icon` should as `Favourite_icon1`. So that I am checking Whether the college is already favourited by using server `API`. So how can I set the menu bar Icon from oncreate() method.

Comment: Please provide us some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Android menu bar, you shouldn't try and change it in `onCreate()`, because it hasn't been instantiated, and will always throw a `NullPointerException`.

If you are waiting for an API response to find the favorites, you will need to create a local menu variable to access it.

```
Menu myMenu;

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    myMenu = menu;
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then, whatever your server API's callback method should do something like this:

```
void callback(boolean favorite) {
    if (favorite) {
        myMenu.findItem(R.id.myMenuItem).setIcon(R.drawable.Favourite_icon1);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain where i want to check with server wheather in onprepareOptionMenu or callback

Comment: Callback was just an example for whatever a callback might be for your API callback. I can't say when the best time to call it would be since I don't know how your application works. You can make the API call in `onCreate` if you want, but you can't operate on the menu until later in the lifecycle (after the menu has been initialized).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ...
        isSomethingInMenu = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_something).setVisible(isSomethingInMenu);
        ...
    }
```